# Rails : gem "dynamoid" list_tables error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-dynamodb

I'm not new to DynamoDB, but I'm new to DynamoID gem.
I can't achieve to make it work since I get the following error :

```
/aws-sdk-1.28.1/lib/aws/core/client.rb:366:in `return_or_raise': The action or operation requested is invalid. Verify that the action is typed correctly. (AWS::DynamoDB::Errors::InvalidAction)
/aws-sdk-1.28.1/lib/aws/core/client.rb:467:in `client_request'
(eval):3:in `list_tables'
/aws-sdk-1.28.1/lib/aws/dynamo_db/table_collection.rb:121:in `_each_item'
/aws-sdk-1.28.1/lib/aws/core/collection/with_limit_and_next_token.rb:54:in `_each_batch'
/aws-sdk-1.28.1/lib/aws/core/collection.rb:80:in `each_batch'
/aws-sdk-1.28.1/lib/aws/core/collection.rb:47:in `each'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid/adapter/aws_sdk.rb:185:in `collect'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid/adapter/aws_sdk.rb:185:in `list_tables'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:146:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Adapter>'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:39:in `benchmark'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:146:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Adapter>'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:25:in `block in reconnect!'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:39:in `benchmark'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:25:in `reconnect!'
/dynamoid-0.7.1/lib/dynamoid.rb:35:in `configure'
app/config/initializers/dynamoid.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

It seems that list_tables doesn't exist, but it's a method of the AWS Ruby SDK
My model is very simple :

```
class Interaction

    include Dynamoid::Document
    table :name => :interactions, :key => :from, :read_capacity => 1, :write_capacity => 1

end
```

Could anybody help?

Cheers,
Emmanuel

Comment: i assume that your AWS configuration is not right. please post it here removing all the secret information.

Comment: Hi poet. All my others AWS services work well. You think it could be a different conf for dynamoid ?